# Retrieve data from join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am new in RoR and I am trying to write a query on a join table that retrieve all the data I need

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :forms, :through => :user_forms
end

class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, :through => :user_forms
end
```

In my controller I can successfully retrieve all the forms of a user like this :

```
User.find(params[:u]).forms
```

Which gives me all the Form objects

But, I would like to add a new column in my join table (user_forms) that tells the status of the form (close, already filled, etc).

Is it possible to modify my query so that it can also retrieve columns from the user_forms table ?

Comment: Do you mean filter out by status :'close', 'already filled' etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible. Once you've added the `status` column to `user_forms`, try the following

```
>> user = User.first
>> closed_forms = user.forms.where(user_forms: { status: 'closed' })
```

Take note that you don't need to add a joins because that's taken care of when you called `user.forms`.

UPDATE: to add an attribute from the `user_forms` table to the forms, try the following

```
>> closed_forms = user.forms.select('forms.*, user_forms.status as status')
>> closed_forms.first.status # should return the status of the form that is in the user_forms table
```

Comment: wow, everyday I discover a new way to do things in rails. Thanks. However, I would like to retrieve all the forms but with the status column (as in my app, the administrator should be able to see the status of the form).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this using `find_by_sql` and literal sql. I do not know of a way to properly chain together rails query methods to create the same query, however.

But here's a modified example that I put together for a friend previously:

```
@user = User.find(params[:u])
@forms = @user.forms.find_by_sql("SELECT forms.*, user_forms.status as status FROM forms INNER JOIN user_forms ON forms.id = user_forms.form_id WHERE (user_forms.user_id = #{@user.id});")
```

And then you'll be able to do

```
@forms.first.status
```

and it'll act like `status` is just an attribute of the `Form` model.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you made a mistake.

When you have 2 models having `has_many` relations, you should set an `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation.

In most cases, 2 models are joined by

- `has_many` - `belongs_to`
- `has_one` - `belongs_to`
- `has_and_belongs_to_many` - `has_and_belongs_to_many`

`has_and_belongs_to_many` is one of the solutions. But, if you choose it, you must create a join table named `forms_users`. Choose an `has_and_belongs_to_many` implies you can not set a status on the join table.

For it, you have to add a join table, with a form_id, a user_id and a status.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_forms
    has_many :forms, :through => :user_forms
end

class UserForm < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :form
end

class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_forms
    has_many :users, :through => :user_forms
end
```

Then, you can get

```
User.find(params[:u]).user_forms
```

Or

```
UserForm.find(:all,
  :conditions => ["user_forms.user_id = ? AND user_forms.status = ?",
     params[:u],
     'close'
  )
)
```

Comment: I have tried to play with habtm but I found it too restrictive. Your query works but it retrieve a UserForm object so I don't have all the informations of the form table (like, name for example)

Answer (score 0):

Given that status is really a property of Form, you probably want to add the status to the Forms table rather than the join table.

Then when you retrieve forms using your query, they will already have the status information retrieved with them i.e.

```
User.find(params[:u]).forms.each{ |form| puts form.status }
```

Additionally, if you wanted to find all the forms for a given user with a particular status, you can use queries like:

`User.find(params[:u]).forms.where(status: 'closed')`

Comment: The status is relative to both the user and the form (if a user has filled a form for exemple).